# Fetching data isn't printing or displaying in frontend

Tags: reactjs, database, get, postman

So i have a code here of me getting my users data so its like this in postman
[image]

now when i do it in frontend its not fetching the data of it this is the hook state of my code

```
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const records = await axios.get('/api/users')
      setRecords(records)
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [])
```

and this is the example of me getting the first_name data

```
 <div>
          <ul>
            {records.map((record, index) => {
              return <li key={index}>{record.email_address}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` returns an HTTP response, not just the contents. Use the `data` property and this should work.

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('/api/users')
      setRecords(res.data)
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's returns a response as well. take a look at the following code-

```js
   


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const records = await axios.get('/api/users').then((response) => {

        setRecords(response.data)
      })
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, []);
```